# How do these 2 notations differ in meaning in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Came across these 2 notations recently. While both appear to be doing similar things, one of them uses an assignment operator while another one appears to be an object. Are they doing anything different?

```js
const { value = "" } = this.props;
```

and

```js
let { value: newValue } = newProps;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with React library actually. They are [ES6 destructuring assignments.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Destructuring_assignment)

The first example will create a constant variable called `value` and will assign whatever is `this.props.value` (Object, Array, Number). If `this.props.value` is undefined though it will use default value `= ""` - empty string.

```
const { value = "" } = this.props;
```

In a second example, `newValue` variable will be created and it will equal to `newProps.value` (even if it is undefined).

```
let { value: newValue } = newProps;
```

Answer (score 4):

Both of these are destructing an object. When you use `=` you are setting a default value if the value is undefined/null. With `:` you are aliasing the variable. You can even combine them:

```
const { value : value2 = 'Hello' } = this.props;

console.log(this.props.value); // World
console.log(value2); // World (since value2 IS this.props.value aliased)

// ...or if this.props.value isn't defined
console.log(value2); // Hello
```